# Commonly used stripe options

Tags: linux, network-storage, raid

I'm looking for commonly used stripe options like chunk-size and stripe width etc.
I'm looking to create stripe environment for large files

Comment: @laks: do you have any more context for this question? What application(s), disk size(s), disk type(s), distribution(s)?

Answer (score 0):

Benchmark, benchmark, benchmark. Then benchmark some more. Try out different configurations and see which ones are the fastest.

For large files you will probably want 'large' chunk-sizes and stripe widths.